# Storm tuple.getIntegerByField not working as expected

Tags: apache-storm

I have a tuple with the below data
first column is `"affectedAccount"`

```
 source: source-spout:12, stream: default, id: {}, [1, 11455455, 1288, 20180717, 000808, 1, 6, 1, d, 1, Y, 1.250000, 6, , , , , , , ]
```

when I run

```
tuple.getIntegerByField("affectedAccount");
```

it throws `ClassCastException`
while when I run

```
 this.affectedAccount = Integer.parseInt(tuple.getStringByField("affectedAccount"));
```

it works okey, why it didn't work eventhough the value is Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the type of the first column isn't actually Integer, but String. Take a look at the implementation of Tuple.getIntegerByField https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/efb2e9a337f9320efd7e5873e493532aa58f341c/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/tuple/TupleImpl.java#L174.

The reason `this.affectedAccount = Integer.parseInt(tuple.getStringByField("affectedAccount"));` works is that the field is actually of String type.

Comment: What do you mean by "the field is actually of String type." ? 
and I can see it's implemented as return (Integer) values.get(fieldIndex(field));
so where can I set the field type ?

Comment: I mean that the spout (or other bolt?) you're receiving the tuple from has put a String in the "affectedAccount" field, rather than an Integer (so `"1"` instead of `1`). You'd have to look at the upstream bolt/spout to figure out how to change the type.

Comment: the spout is just reading a file and emitting it's content, and I've also overrided the declareOutputFields method.

Comment: Okay, but is the Java type of the object you're putting in Values' first parameter in the spout an int/Integer?